# how to draw heart using java awt libaray? also depends on position and size?

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

how to draw heart using java awt libaray? Below I wrote code which display a heart:

```
public class heart{
 publicheart(int x, int y){...}
 public heart(int x, int y, int width, int height){...}

...
    int[] xp = { x, x + 41, x + 20 };
    int[] yp = { y + 14, y + 14, y + 30 };
    g.setColor(Color.pink.darker());

    g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20); //left circle
    g.fillOval(x + 20, y, 20, 20); //to cover middle spot
    g.fillOval(x + 13, y + 10, 10, 10); //right circle
    g.fillPolygon(xp, yp, xp.length); //bottom triangle
}
```

now lets say I want to call this class and print a heart.

```
heart h = new heart(100, 100);
```

as you can see this work fine bc my x and y depends on heart class so I can create whatever position.

**Problem:**
How can I change my code so it depends on x, y, width, and height? ex:

```
heart h = new heart(100, 100, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw heart using java awt libaray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402242/how-to-draw-heart-using-java-awt-libaray)

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402242/how-to-draw-heart-using-java-awt-libaray